# Not getting output for division and modulus

Tags: c

The below C program gives me output only for Addition(+), difference(-), multiplication(*).
But when I try to use division(/) and modulus(%) the program just close itself without giving any error. Help me I'm a newbie to C programming.

```
//A simple calculator.

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int a, b, sum, diff, rem, multi;
float div;
char character;
clrscr();
printf("Choose the character you want to use(+, -, *, /, %): ");
scanf("%c", &character);
switch(character)
{
case '+': //will be used for addition.
    printf("Enter the first and second number: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    sum = a+b;
    printf("The sum of the %d and %d is %d", a, b, sum);
    break;
case '-': //will be used for difference.
    printf("Enter the first and second number: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    diff = a-b;
    printf("The difference between %d and %d is %d", a, b, diff);
    break;
case '%': //will be used for modulus.
    printf("Enter the first and second number: ");
    scanf("%f %f", &a, &b);
    rem = a%b;
    printf("The remainder of %f and %f is %f", a, b, rem);
    break;
case '*': //will be used for product of 2 no.
    printf("Enter the first and second number: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    multi = a*b;
    printf("The multiplication of %d and %d is %d", a, b, multi);
    break;
case '/': //will be used for the division.
    printf("Enter the first and second number: ");
    scanf("%f %f", &a, &b);
    div = a/b;
    printf("The division of %f and %f is %f", a, b, div);
    break;
default:
    printf("Error! character please retry");
}
getch();
}
```

Comment: Please add `-Wall` to your gcc command line and it will start to through a lot of warnings. Fe.x. `%f` is an incorrect format, it should be `%d`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `%f` format specifier for `int` variables in `/` and `%` cases.

```
scanf("%f %f", &a, &b);
```

Thus invoking undefined behavior.

Change it to as below.

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
```

> `%f` is used to readin the float variables.

---

If you want float result for division, you need to cast the one of the argument to float instead reading them as `float`.

```
  div = (float)a/b;
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the **/** and **%** use

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%f %f", &a, &b);
```

because %f is used for float vars whereas in case of **/ and %** %d is used

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong formats. After enabling `-Wall` in gcc and fixing the warnings I get a working program. You also missing the `\n` in your answer `printf()`'s

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int a, b, sum, diff, rem, multi;
  float div;
  char character;
  printf("Choose the character you want to use(+, -, *, /, %%): ");
  scanf("%c", &character);
  switch(character)
    {
    case '+': //will be used for addition.
      printf("Enter the first and second number: ");
      scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
      sum = a+b;
      printf("The sum of the %d and %d is %d\n", a, b, sum);
      break;
    case '-': //will be used for difference.
      printf("Enter the first and second number: ");
      scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
      diff = a-b;
      printf("The difference between %d and %d is %d\n", a, b, diff);
      break;
    case '%': //will be used for modulus.
      printf("Enter the first and second number: ");
      scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
      rem = a%b;
      printf("The remainder of %d and %d is %d\n", a, b, rem);
      break;
    case '*': //will be used for product of 2 no.
      printf("Enter the first and second number: ");
      scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
      multi = a*b;
      printf("The multiplication of %d and %d is %d\n", a, b, multi);
      break;
    case '/': //will be used for the division.
      printf("Enter the first and second number: ");
      scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
      div = a/b;
      printf("The division of %d and %d is %f\n", a, b, div);
      break;
    default:
      printf("Error! character please retry");
    }
}
```

Test output:

```
$ ./dummy
Choose the character you want to use(+, -, *, /, %): %
Enter the first and second number: 5 2
The remainder of 5 and 2 is 1
$
```